# How long can a silicone and white spirit solution be stored without hardening?

Tags: stability, solvents, organosilicon-compounds

I’ve heard that some people use a mixture of silicone and white spirit to waterproof their gear.

How long this solution can be stored without hardening if it is stored in a closed hermetic bottle?

If the solution does harden over time, what would be the cause of this? Does anyone have any information or experience with this?

(Additionally, since it’s not really possible to preserve an opened tube of caulk ―which I’m only using for this purpose―, I wonder if I can increase my chances of not spoiling it by storing it in this state).

Comment: In my test, it did not last 24h

Answer (score 1):

"White Spirit" or [naphtha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_spirit) will [*dissolve*](https://www.pfonline.com/articles/silicone-oil-removal) silicone oils. Water will not.
Therein lies the secret of using silicone as a water proofing agent.

It is applied, much like paint, and the solvent evaporates, leaving a film.

Best chances of [preserving](https://www.denbraven.com/en/knowledge-base/chemical-resistance-silicones/) it would be to store in a cool place, away from sunlight or heat, in a tightly sealed container, again much like an oil based paint.

Comment: Thanks but you don't answer the question: "*How long* can it be stored without hardening? [in this condition]". (As long as sealed container of oil based paint?)

Comment: @JinSnow obviously shelf life is highly dependent on a number of factors.  I suggest it may be possible that a silicone/spirit mixture may have a shelf life in the range of a sealed container of oil based paint.  As always, common sense indicates that more definitive answers may be had with actual testing, as compared with internet thread sources (it may not harden at all as long as solvent is present and the silicone does not degrade).